# OpenCv: Using Yolov3

Tags: c++, opencv, darknet, yolo

I used the OpenCV Code from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d9d/tutorial_dnn_yolo.html and made it work on my machine with the yolov2 config/weights. When I try to run the program with yolov3 config/weights (https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights, https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3.cfg. both working, when used in ubuntu / not in opencv), it fails on the line

```
dnn::Net net = readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelBinary);
```

The Exception is:

> Unhandled exception at 0xyz in xyz.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0xyz.

The expected behavior would be, that it shows the recognition results, like it does with the yolov2 cfg/weights.

Is yolov3 even usable in opencv?

Thanks,
Michel

---

Update: Question was answered below. I made a issue in github: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11310

---

**Update v2**: yolov3 is now supported in opencv. -> https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11310 includes an example of the usage

Comment: Please provide a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also provide the full error message. "It fails" is never specific enough.

Comment: @NOhs Thanks for your feedback. The question should now be more specific. The code is there, the parameters to run the programm with. The exception does not seem very meaningful to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Yolo v2 is supported as of 2018/04/11, see the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9705).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you now if the yolov3 compatibility is planned and how to get informed, when it arrives?

Comment: @SoullessStone, YOLO-v3 is a relatively new model so feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues including full name of the model, references to `.cfg` and `.weights` files. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev, Thanks! I improved my description and made a ticket.
-> https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11310